# Wikidata: How to represent British Hong Kong's under Japanese occupation?

Tags: wikidata

Between 1941 and 1945, British Hong Kong (then a colony) was occupied by the Japanese, see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Hong_Kong#Japanese_occupation_era_(1940s)).

However on British Hong Kong's [Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1054923) page, there's no mention of the Japaneses occupation whatsoever. It seems like it was a British colony or dependent territory from  1841 to 1997.

I'm willing to contribute to Wikidata to fix this, but what's the best way to model this short-term occupation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no methodological guidelines for how to model those things on Wikidata.
Rerardless Wikidata, modelling of such geopolitical endurants/perdurants/aggregates might be fairly [complex](http://ebooks.iospress.nl/volumearticle/50244).

**Option 1**

- Create a separate "Japanese-occupied Hong Kong" entry (similar to [Vichy France](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q69808)).
- Split [British Hong Kong](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1054923) into "British-occupied Hong Kong" and "British-reoccupied Hong Kong"
  (similar to [French Third Republic](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q70802) and [French Fourth Republic](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q69829)).

Thereafter, one should split into two parts [all 26 Wikipedia articles](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1054923#sitelinks-wikipedia)...

**Option 2**

[image: using the 'instance of' property]

**Option 3**

[image: using the 'country' property]

---

Your question is widely [applicable](https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?search=&search=Japanese+occupation&title=Special%3ASearch&go=Go).

Perhaps you could [propose](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Property_proposal) the "occupied by" property.